# Simple DELETE php pdo query

Tags: php, sql, sql-delete

I want to delete data but with multiple condition so I write this:

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("DELETE FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE (ID,ajdi), VALUES(:id,:ajdi)");

            $STH->bindParam(':id', $_POST['vrednostid']);
        $STH->bindParam(':ajdi', $_POST['ajdi']);
```

but I have error is statement? What do I need to change?

Answer (score 3):

your SQL syntax is wrong. It should be

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("DELETE FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE ID=:id AND ajdi=:ajdi");
$STH->bindParam(':id', $_POST['vrednostid']);
$STH->bindParam(':ajdi', $_POST['ajdi']);
$STH->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM track_aktivnosti WHERE (ID = ? and ajdi = ?)");
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['vrednostid'],$_POST['ajdi']));
```